# Remove root tags from an XML document before adding the XML to another file

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

I'm trying to add several chunks of XML code from one file into another. The problem is, some of these chunks have root tags that don't need to be copied into the destination XML file (that's the case if the root tags equal the pre-defined parent tags). Here's the code I'm currently using to insert the snippet (written in Groovy):

```
if (addCode.nodeName == parentTags) { //meaning the root tags shouldn't be included
    for (org.w3c.dom.Node n : addCode.childNodes) {
        //parent is a NodeList
        parent.item(parent.length - 1).appendChild(document.importNode(n, true))
    }
} else {
    parent.item(parent.length - 1).appendChild(document.importNode(addCode, true))
}
```

And to parse the XML:

```
Document parseWithoutDTD(Reader r, boolean validating = false, boolean namespaceAware = true) {
    FactorySupport.createDocumentBuilderFactory().with { f ->
        f.namespaceAware = namespaceAware
        f.validating = validating
        f.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
        f.newDocumentBuilder().with { db ->
            db.parse(new InputSource(r))
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example XML file where the root tags shouldn't be included:

```
<catalogue> <!-- shouldn't be included -->
    <message key='type_issuedate'>Date Issued</message>
    <message key='type_accessioneddate'>Date Accesioned</message>
</catalogue>
```

You might have noticed the problem: if I leave out the root tags from the XML files to copy into the other XML file, they throw a parsing exception.

**EDIT:** here's an (shortened) example of the file to insert to:

```
<catalogue xml:lang="en" xmlns:i18n="http://apache.org/cocoon/i18n/2.1">
    ...
    <message key="column4">Date</message>
    <message key="column5">Summary</message>
    <message key="column6">Actions</message>
    <message key="restore">Restore</message>
    <message key="update">Update</message>
    <!-- INSERT XML HERE -->
    ...
</catalogue>
```

And an example of XML with root tags to be included (and the corresponding file to insert to):

**XML to insert**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>grID</groupId>
    <artifactId>artID</artifactId>
    <version>${version.number}</version>
</dependency>
```

**XML file to insert into**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>grID1</groupId>
        <artifactId>artID1</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <classifier>classes</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <!-- INSERT XML HERE -->
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Currently, all of this code isn't working as I want it to work. Can someone help me out?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?  Do you have an example of the document you're trying to add to?  And an example where the root tags should be included?

Answer (score 0):

I think (if I understand right), you need something like this:

```
def insert( parent, data ) {
  if( parent.name() == data.name() ) {
    data.children().each {
      parent.append it
    }
  }
  else {
    parent.append data
  }
}
```

So, given

```
def newdoc = '''<dependency>
               |    <groupId>grID</groupId>
               |    <artifactId>artID</artifactId>
               |    <version>${version.number}</version>
               |</dependency>'''.stripMargin()

def doc = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            |<project>
            |  <dependencies>
            |    <dependency>
            |        <groupId>grID1</groupId>
            |        <artifactId>artID1</artifactId>
            |        <type>jar</type>
            |        <classifier>classes</classifier>
            |    </dependency>
            |  </dependencies>
            |</project>'''.stripMargin()

def docnode = new XmlParser().parseText( doc )
def newnode = new XmlParser().parseText( newdoc )

// use head() as I want to add to the first dependencies node
insert( docnode.dependencies.head(), newnode )
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( docnode )
```

You get the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>grID1</groupId>
      <artifactId>artID1</artifactId>
      <type>jar</type>
      <classifier>classes</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>grID</groupId>
      <artifactId>artID</artifactId>
      <version>${version.number}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And given:

```
def newdoc = '''<catalogue>
               |    <message key='type_issuedate'>Date Issued</message>
               |    <message key='type_accessioneddate'>Date Accesioned</message>
               |</catalogue>'''.stripMargin()

def doc = '''<catalogue xml:lang="en" xmlns:i18n="http://apache.org/cocoon/i18n/2.1">
            |    <message key="column4">Date</message>
            |    <message key="column5">Summary</message>
            |    <message key="column6">Actions</message>
            |    <message key="restore">Restore</message>
            |    <message key="update">Update</message>
            |</catalogue>'''.stripMargin()

def docnode = new XmlParser().parseText( doc )
def newnode = new XmlParser().parseText( newdoc )

insert( docnode, newnode )
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( docnode )
```

you get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><catalogue xml:lang="en" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
  <message key="column4">Date</message>
  <message key="column5">Summary</message>
  <message key="column6">Actions</message>
  <message key="restore">Restore</message>
  <message key="update">Update</message>
  <message key="type_issuedate">Date Issued</message>
  <message key="type_accessioneddate">Date Accesioned</message>
</catalogue>
```

---

### Edit

Ok, given the extra info, does this help?  Given the same `newdoc` and `doc` strings as above, this script seems to do what you want...

```
import groovy.xml.*
import groovy.xml.dom.*
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

Document parseWithoutDTD(Reader r, boolean validating = false, boolean namespaceAware = true) {
    FactorySupport.createDocumentBuilderFactory().with { f ->
        f.namespaceAware = namespaceAware
        f.validating = validating
        f.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
        f.newDocumentBuilder().with { db ->
            db.parse(new InputSource(r))
        }
    }
}

def addCode  = parseWithoutDTD( new StringReader( newdoc ) ).documentElement
def document = parseWithoutDTD( new StringReader( doc ) )
def parent   = document.documentElement
def parentTags = 'catalogue'

use( DOMCategory ) {
  if( addCode.nodeName == parentTags ) {
    addCode.childNodes.each { node ->
      parent.appendChild( document.importNode( node, true ) )
    }
  }
  else {
    parent.appendChild( document.importNode( addCode, true ) )
  }
}
```

Comment: This confuses me. Isn't there any solution involving the code I use already? Because using your code - thanks for that, btw! - would require for me to rewrite alot of my code..

Comment: @Dreamonic what code do you have already?  How do you parse the xml?  How do you get to having `addCode` and `parentTags` variables?  You don't say in your question, so fitting an answer would be pure guesswork

Comment: `addCode` (Element) is just the XML snippet to be added parsed, without validation, including namespaces.

`parentTags` is just a String from a properties file (f.e. `dependencies` could be a value for `parentTags`).

The code I'm using to add the snippets is in the question, top code block (it's shortened for readability, because posting all code here would result in a very, very long question).

Comment: @Dreamonic how are you parsing the xml?

Comment: Using the method you've described earlier. I've updated the question :)

Comment: @Dreamonic Soz, I forgot ;-)  Updated answer...does it help?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29307/discussion-between-dreamonic-and-tim-yates)